# Erro ao navegar entre as telas com Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, native

Estou com problema ao chamar uma segunda ViewController dentro do método **RowSelected** em uma class que contem a interface **UITableViewSource**, ao fazer a chama mesmo instanciando a ViewControlller ocorre um erro "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", mas estou batendo a cabeça para resolver este problema, alguém saberia me informar o que está ocorrendo?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ClickDeliveryMobile.IOS.Views;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;


namespace ClickDeliveryMobile.IOS.DataSources
{
public class CategoriaTableViewSource: UITableViewSource
{
    private List<string> ListCategorias;

    public CategoriaTableViewSource(List<string> ListCategorias)
    {
        this.ListCategorias = ListCategorias;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "");


        cell.TextLabel.Text = ListCategorias[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return ListCategorias.Count;
    }
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var selecionaCat = ListCategorias[indexPath.Row];


        CategoriaViewController categoria = new CategoriaViewController();

        categoria.NavigationController.PushViewController(new SobreViewController(), true);

        Console.WriteLine(selecionaCat);
    }

}
}
```